# ISAPI web application hanging if FastReport.PrepareReport is called

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, isapi, fastreport

```
begin
  try
    Raport.PrepareReport(True);
  except on E:Exception do
    raise ;
  end;
//  if Raport.Engine.Run then
  Raport.Export(frxPDF);
end;
```

When running as an Isapi dll the web application hangs o Raport.PrepareReport(true), when running with a local application server as an .exe application it runs!...
The folder has permissions for total control files for IIS_IUSRS.
Why it would be hanging?

Comment: Doing everything in the context of the IIS web request can be troublesome. Have you considered asynchronous processing, where the report generation is performed by a separate (service-type) application?

Comment: I've developed a service for create the report. But... It hangs too at prepareReport(True) sentence.... 
Perhaps it needs some windows services activated... or... internally points to a folder (as TempFolder from Windows)... without permissions... I cann't generate the report yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a RichEdit control, that isn´t supported for ISAPI fxReport

Comment: Thank you very much, this same problem has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced if there is an unhandled exception in the ISAPI dll the app crashes. You're handling the general exception E: Exception but re-raising it to pass over to a higher level handler. So, if there's no upper level handler, it goes to IIS and this makes IIS to make the app crash, since from the IIS perspective there was an unhandled exception and it has no idea how to handle it.

You should not re-raise the exceptions happening in ISAPI; if you're at the highest handler, just handle it properly. Try write back E.message for example to investigate further to understand what happened and what caused the exception in the first place.

Comment: Debugging code, never go to raise line, the program hang in PrepareReport line.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the PrepareReport method. You should trace into to it and pinpoint the line that causing the exception.

Comment: The PrepareReport is in dcu file. I haven't the .pas for debugging ..., but always hangs there

Answer (score 1):

i have the same web service and use fast report as report generate and it work like a charm
but you should set this properties

```
      FrxRep.ShowProgress := False;
      FrxRep.ReportOptions.Clear;
      FrxRep.EngineOptions.SilentMode := True;
  frxPDFExport1.ShowProgress    := False;
  frxPDFExport1.ShowDialog      := False;
  frxPDFExport1.OverwritePrompt := False;
```

be sure that you never use ui relative commands like showmessage or messagedlg and ...