# Delphi - ISAPI DLL Application hanging on Fastreport

Tags: delphi, rtf, isapi, fastreport, iis-10

Found this this post [ISAPI web application hanging if FastReport.PrepareReport is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607416/isapi-web-application-hanging-if-fastreport-preparereport-is-called)

It helped solving my problem partially. As well I´ve turned `Wisiyng` property to `False` on `frxRichView.` Since I'm retunrnig a `base 64 string` I've also tryed switched loading from `StrToStream/LoadFromStream` to `LoadFromFile`. The problem persist with multiple acess, 2 out of 10 process can finish loading my `Pdf` file. All the others requests hangs until timeout. Does anyone have an idea what else can I do? is there anyother way to retunr `rtf` format into `Fastreport` report Thanks.

I could only get time-out error using `Selenium` to test multiples request from the client side.

Update: I've figured that just having a `TfrxRichView` component in the report causes the hanging, it doesn't even need to have a `rtf` text on it. Replacing it to a `memo` all request are answered.

**UPDATE:** Got a answer from fast report and I wold like your opinion.
[image]

Comment: what pdf export filter are you using?

Comment: Its frxPdfExport

Comment: which fast report version are you using? have you source?

Comment: v5.6 but i have also try on v6.0.4

Comment: Its kind of a lot of a coding but ill try to build a example so u have an idea...

Comment: updated question

Comment: Question updated. Anyway I am gonna try all the answers you guys gave  first thanks.

Comment: Got a answer from fast report but I wold like your opinion. they said : "Windows Rich control is not thread-safe, don't use it in the multi-thread application".

Answer (score 0):

ok,
I had similar problems, and it is not easy to find out the reason, but maybe you can find your solution in between my considerations..

**1) Stack Size**
When ran in IIS your ISAPI is only a DLL called by a process, you are not the main process so you have to pay attention to stack dimension.
Normally a Delphi application have a default stack size of 1Mb, in ISAPI DLL you will have only 256Kb of stack.
Maybe you are facing a stack overflow exception.. it can explain why it does not occurr always but only in some circumstances..

**2) Trapped Exception**
In general you get some error during the preparation of report (aka all the job of working with data, expressions, variables, formulas etc etc..) can bring to a trapped exception. You may be unable to see it from outside but code execution was broken somwhere and report preparation had not finished.

**3) MessageBoxes and/or standard Exceptions**
when running in ISAPI you should not output anything to user interface, 
maybe a message dialog (or an exception) can bring to unexpected behaviour.

**4) Global Var**
You should avoid global var because in ISAPI they will be common across threads

So, if you have sources, debug the application.. at first exception you should understand where is your problem..
If you have not sources.. chek the above list.. I hope you can find some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this:

1- Try to recreate this behavior while debugging your ISAPI DLL. If you are lucky, you can identify the thread that is hanging your application. Sometimes this is hard or even impossible to recreate.

2- If you have access to the hung ISAPI application instance, use a tool like SysInternals Process Explorer to create a minidump file. Your application must be built using full debug symbols and you should have the corresponding map file. With one (or more - even better) dump files obtained from your hung application plus the map file, you can use another tool, WinDbg to analyze it and find the cause. (Sometimes) WinDbg can show exactly which thread is hanging the whole application and the line of code that causes it.

If you have never done that, I must warn you that this kind of analysis is almost a gamble... You have to use several different tools with little 
or no documentation, read heaps of technical info in various places. In the end, sometimes it works wonderfully and sometimes it fails miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Because debugging ISAPI is not obvious, but also because I wanted to be able to switch easily between more different hosting solutions — **and** wanted to update my website *on the fly* without a restart of the web-server/service — I created [xxm](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm). It has a singular interface to the HTTP context, your DLL gets loaded by either a IIS ISAPI handler, or a HTTP.SYS handler, or an Apache httpd module, or for debugging locally you can just set `xxmHttp.exe` as host application to get IIS out of the way.